# Complex analysis visualization (Cauchy Theorem, Residue Theorem)?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, visualization

I usually think of complex functions on the complex plane like vector fields. So basically what I have problems with is visualizing firstly Holomorphic functions. I have also read and successfully understood the proofs of the Cauchy Theorem over cycles as well as the Residue Theorem (Rudin) and some of their applications. I would like to know if any of you has a way of visualizing or making these theorems more intuitive as to why they happen.

Comment: Have you seen the book [Visual Complex Analysis](http://usf.usfca.edu/vca/)?

Comment: "Visual Complex Analysis", by T. Needham . Why to omit the author's name?